# Is "going loco" a common AmE expression?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, trumpism

The title of the following article posted today by CNBC uses the expression *going loco* with quotation marks.

> "[Trump doubles down on Fed attacks, saying it’s ‘going loco’](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/10/11/trump-doubles-down-on-fed-attacks-saying-its-going-loco.html)"

(Video from [CNN](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=PPi9QvGBGog) at 0:46)

Loco, as suggested by [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/loco) is an AmE slang expression:

> - Slang. out of one's mind; insane; crazy. (1835–45, Americanism; < Spanish: insane)

and a [Google Book](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20loco%2Cgoing%20loco%2C%20going%20crazy%2C%20go%20crazy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20loco%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20loco%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20crazy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20crazy%3B%2Cc0) search suggests a limited usage of *go/going loco* vs *go/going crazy*.

I suppose the cited article used quotation marks because the expression is very informal and uncommon in writing, but is it commonly used and understood in speaking nowadays? or is it sort of old-fashioned expression?

Comment: How old is "old fashioned"? It’s in a [song](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loco_in_Acapulco) from the 80s.

Comment: @Pam - I am referring more to everyday usage in informal conversations.

Comment: Not Books, because it's slang.

Comment: "I suppose the cited article used quotation marks because the expression is very informal and uncommon in writing"—I think the explanation is simpler than that: the most natural interpretation of quotation marks in the title of a news article is that they indicate a direct quotation.

Comment: @sumelic - you mean Trump said "going loco"?

Comment: Yes; the linked article provides a longer quotation that indicates that Trump said "going loco" in the context of the sentence "The Fed is going loco and there's no reason for them to do it."

Comment: @sumelic - Great...so if the President says "going loco" it means that the expression is alive and kicking, I suppose.

Comment: @sumelic - It is from yesterday, after the Dow collapsed he started accusing the FED for raising the rates too quickly...

Comment: You might also consider that he's fairly old and, like most old people trying to use modern slang, is outdated by a few years. Personally, I haven't heard that expression used by people my age in about a decade.

Comment: @SomethingDark - I did consider that, from which my question.

Comment: "Seth Meyers wants to know why Trump always points to his own head when he says ‘loco’" *Watch Trump go loco in the video below.* https://www.rawstory.com/2018/10/seth-meyers-wants-to-know-why-trump-always-points-to-his-own-head-when-he-says-loco/

Comment: "Loco" is familiar to anyone who watched TV westerns in the 50s and 60s.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+loco%2C+went+loco%2C+going+loco&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20loco%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20loco%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgoing%20loco%3B%2Cc0

Comment: There's the word 'loco' and then there's the additional phrasing 'to go loco'. (to me, just 'loco' is slang that other people might use but sounds weird in my mouth; 'to go loco' sounds old-timey movie toothless old gold prospector.

Comment: @Mitch - so we might say it was just an eccentric expression by the President, I suppose.

Comment: @user240918 Sure. Odd but not unrecognizable. "That durn mule's gone plumb loco." is how I imagine a hack writer for a poorly produced gold rush drama might write it.

Comment: @Mitch - that’s probably the image that Trump tried to convey.

Answer (score 3):

> Is “going loco” a common AmE expression?

**loco**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109634?rskey=5vAoDV&result=4#eid)

> colloq. orig. U.S. regional (western). Mad, insane, crazy; off one's head. Frequently in **to go loco**.

As in:

> “A vote for Republicans is a vote . . . to reclaim America’s true
>   heritage and righteous destiny. We’re losing that with these crazy
>   **loco** people,” he said on Saturday. Washington Post **2018**

and

> Crazy as the Kings are, they’re not **loco** enough to trade him to
>   their hated division rival. Forbes **2015**

and

> He smiled and jokingly called Kemp “**loco**” -- the Spanish word for
>   crazy. Los Angeles Times **2014**

and

> Central Bankers Defend Fed After Trump Accuses It of ‘**Going Loco**’
>   [Bloomberg Oct. 11, **2018**](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-10-11/central-bankers-say-fed-not-going-loco-as-trump-sounds-off?utm_source=google&utm_medium=bd&cmpId=google)

Yes, it is used frequently enough in AmE to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

You may not find it much in nGrams because the term is informal.

"The Influence of Spanish on the English Language since 1801: A Lexical Investigation," Julia Schultz, Cambridge Scholars Publishing, 2018, (GoogleBooks) has this to say:

> (p.[115](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KPlVDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA115))
>   **(3.3) Adjectives … loco**, adj. (1852).  
> (p.[121](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KPlVDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121))
>   "… originally recorded in regional AmE, translates as "crazy" or "mad," just like its Spanish source term. It can also be used in the phrase *to go loco* in present-day English, as in:
>   
> 2003 *National Post (Toronto)* 3 June al2/4. It was at the MacKay party … where political animals actually went loco on the dance floor (*OED3*)

From Spanish *loco*; 1852. Note the **present-day** phrase *to go loco* mentioned above, the example cited is dated 2003 and the book is published this year.

Of course, Kevin D. Burns Jr., "**Brown Lady**," in "Heart… Who Goes There?" 2010 [p.13](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wisZ8Wb9ox4C&pg=PA13) (GoogleBooks)

> I know it sounds crazy but you're mybrown skin lady
>   And I go loco over your caramel complexion
>   You're my prime investment
>   The one I put mytime in
>   The reason why this poem goes on line after line and …

Comment: Thanks, but you say nothing about current usage

Comment: 2003 is not too old, and 2010 is in the present decade. And we sure have Donald Trump, too.